# Issue with MQ EBCDIC data conversion (25) interpreted as line feed and converted to 15

Tags: java, ibm-mq, ibm-midrange, mq, tibco

We have an interesting issue that came up.

We have an integration between AS400 system that sends MQ messages in EBCDIC format, picked up by TIBCO BW MQ plugin and processed. These are financial transactions.

The issue we have is that when the data element (packed decimal) contains odd digits like `251`-`259` or `25001`-`25999` etc. the data element is being interpreted by TIBCO BW MQ plugin as `151`-`159` etc.

So we had an amount of `25125` interpreted as `15125` causing a transaction tally missing of $100 (amounts in cents). TIBCO BW MQ plugin uses Java underneath, so this is probably a Java issue. AS400 is able to send and receive as `25125`. But when we browse the message from MQ explorer, we see the data element value rendered as `15125` too.

AS400 team specifies that since they are able to send and receive as `25125` the issue is not on their side. Did anyone encounter a similar issue before? If so, how did you solve it? Is this an issue with MQ client or an issue with AS400 MQ delivering the message?

Comment: PackedDecimal numbers should contain an odd number of digits since the sign(last nibble) is taking 1 digit worth of space(last nibble). If MQ explorer is interpreting the number incorrectly, then it's unlikely that it's an issue on the client. Is the highest digit always being decremented by 1 or is it being bit shifted to the right? Try out 501 and 401. Do they both become 201? or 401 and 301?

Comment: It is only happening for 25 series, others are all fine. Apparently 25 is a newline character representation and is being replaced as 15 when the data is parsed

Comment: We went back and forth with TIBCO Support on engineering builds and it turns out to be an issue with MQ client. Do anyone have any insight if MQ client has support or it is open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for different pointers.

This turned out to be an issue with the java jars provided along with MQ client. It turns out that this particular byte '0x25' has the curious property that when
processed by the JVM in this way and treated as a character encoded in
the CCSID 37 scheme, the output byte is '0x15'.

For example, using a code snippet of the following form:

```
byte[] bytesRepresentation = {(byte)0x25};
String dataAsString = new String(bytesRepresentation, "IBM-037");
byte[] newBytesRepresentation =
dataAsString.getBytes(Charset.forName("IBM-037"));
System.out.println(byteArrayToHexString(bytesRepresentation));
System.out.println(byteArrayToHexString(newBytesRepresentation));
```

the output is:

25
15

ie. the byte sequence has been changed by the byte[]->String->byte[]
processing.

MQ Support had recommended that the sending side change the message property that identifies message format as MQSTR to be changed to default (blank). After doing this, MQ client does not attempt a conversion and TIBCO received this properly from MQ client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TIBCO...

But generally speaking, passing packed data through MQ is a bad idea.

MQ being multi-platform has only two ways to send a message.  As a string and as raw bytes.  When you send it as a string, it will handle converting from one encoding to another as dependent on the platforms involved.

As you can see, treating packed decimal as a string doesn't work.

TIBCO might have the functionality to process the raw message, somewhere in TIBCO (or your Java app?) you have to configure the EBCDIC to ASCII (Unicode) conversion along with unpacking the packed decimal field.  You'd also have to set MQ to send that message raw.

Otherwise, you'll need the IBM i side to unpack the data before sending it as an MQ string message.

Comment: the data is being sent and received as bytes and not as string. When the bytes are parsed, the ones starting with 25 are being replaced with 15.

Comment: If MQ is sending raw bytes, the client is getting raw bytes so the problem lies in either TIBCO or your Java app; whichever is doing the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get numeric data from an EBCDIC machine is through a view that casts the numbers to character.

for example

```
CREATE TABLE DSYLVESTER/ZDAN1 (X1 decimal(3,2) NOT NULL WITH 
DEFAULT)                                                     

select * from dsylvester/zdan1 

3.22

create view qtemp/z3 as (            
SELECT cast( X1 as char(5)) as x1    
 FROM dsylvester/zdan1               

)                                    

select * from qtemp/z3  
3.22
```

Notes:
Call IBM they won't know how to do this.
Call TIBCO they spend more in advertising and sales than they do in development.  TIBCO won't be able to help.

Comment: Thanks Danny, but the MQ Core system did not want to make any changes for this. So we ended up debugging and figuring out the issue. I will post the answer shortly